# I want to use "." in message field name of .proto file

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-java, grpc-python, protobuf-python

I defined *.proto* file like:

```
syntax = "proto3";

message networkSliceArray
{

  int32 DRB.UEThpDl.SNSSAI = 1;

  int32 DRB.UEThpUl.SNSSAI = 2;

  string networkSliceIdentifier = 3;

}
```

I want to parse such type of file. is it possible?
or if not possible is there any reference where i can find out why "." we can not used in protobuf. OR list of character that we can not defined in .proto file.

Comment: Well if you want to parse the file yourself it's possible. However I guess you are asking can you make `protoc` accept this? If that is your question then the answer is no. See the [language specification](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/proto3-spec)) for details of what constitutes a valid `proto3` file (esp. `ident = letter { letter | decimalDigit | "_" }`).

Comment: Why not using sub-messages to do what you want? Is it really just the name that you want like this or is it supposed to represent an object?

Comment: @brits please consider copying your comment as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not really clear but I think you are asking why `protoc` outputs an error when processing the `.proto` file in your question.

[The language specification](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/proto3-spec) sets out what constitutes a valid proto3 file. Your question is about field names so the relevant parts are:

```
field = [ "repeated" ] type fieldName "=" fieldNumber [ "[" fieldOptions "]" ] ";"
fieldName = ident
ident = letter { letter | decimalDigit | "_" }
```

This shows that a field name must start with a letter which can be followed by a combination of letters, digits and underscores. A period (`.`)  is not valid.

Comment: Additional reasons: protoc internally represents type names as `"package.Message.Submessage"`, which would cause problems if the names contained a period in them. Most programming languages also forbid `.` in variable names.